# Looking for a "solvable" function

Tags: functions

I need an increasing and strictly concave function $f(x)$ (that is, $f'(x) > 0; f''(x) < 0$), with which I can find a closed form solution for $x$ in

$$ f(x) + x = c$$

with constant $c$. I started with $f(x) = 2x^{0.5}$, but I couldn't find a closed form solution for $x$ here. Is there any such function $f$? If not, is there any other way to solve for $x$ in my given expression?

Comment: I don't get it. Doesn't your equation just say $f(x)=c-x$, which is not an increasing function?

Comment: @RoryDaulton I first define some $f$, say $\sqrt x$, and then in the second stage I need to be able to solve $\sqrt x + x = c$ for $x$

Comment: Let $Q$ be notation for $\sqrt x$, so $Q^2=x$, and your equation becomes $Q+Q^2=c$. Can you solve that? Can't you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function $f(x)=2\sqrt{x}$ which you already suggest will work. We must use the domain $I=(0,\infty)$ in order that the derivatives exist, and then they have the desired properties $f'>0,\ f''<0$ on interval $I.$

Now we consider the equation $f(x)+x=c,$ where we have the restriction $c>0$ by considering the range of $2\sqrt{x}+x$ on $I.$ We can complete the square after adding $1$ to each side:
$$(\sqrt{x}+1)^2=c+1.$$
From here, $\sqrt{x}+1=+\sqrt{c+1},$ the $+$ sign being forced (since at this point the left side is at least $1$). Finally subtraction of $1$ from the sides and squaring gives the closed form solution for $x$ in terms of $c$ as

$$x=(\sqrt{c+1}-1)^2.$$